# How to set cron job for every 45 days

Tags: cron

I want to send an email after every 45 days using cron job. Since, i have already made php
script for email. So i want to execute it after every 45 days. Can you help me for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 18):

The script can be run daily and wrapped to check if the number of days modulo 45 equals to a constant:

```
10 13 * * *  test $(( `date +\%s`/24/60/60\%45 )) = 41 && your_script
```

I assumed 41 so the expression would evaluate to true today on 2012-01-12. Percent '%' is special character in crontab, it needs to be escaped.

Comment: I can't figure out what the 41 relates to. Could someone help explain?

Comment: I wanted that condition to be true on 2012-01-12 when OP would presumably test this answer. So I calculated that I need to pick "day number 41 of each 45 day period" as a run day.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From Crontab [site](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

There is not really anything here that will do "every 45 days"

I would run your script once a day and have your script check if it has been 45 days since you last sent mail.

```
<?php
    if($days_since_last_email >= 45) {
        //your existing send mail script here
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think Songo's answer is what your looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Same can be implemented by scheduling 2 cron jobs for the script

Starting from 01-Jan-17:

```
0 0 1 1,4,7,10 *  abc.sh

0 0 15 2,5,8,11 *   abc.sh
```

Comment: It should be noted that this won't be *exactly* every 45 days, only roughly every 45 days, thanks to the differing numbers of days per month. Still, if only roughly every 45 days is sufficient, this is a good option. +1

Answer (score -3):

There is way of saying ‘every 45days’, instead you have to specify what specific days you want to run the job. Probably you may want to run the job on 45days.

The third field is for Months. If you specify * in this field, it runs every 45days.

0 0 */45 * * /home/ramesh/backup.sh

try this one

Comment: This is wrong it cause it to run on every 1 day of the months it not like way you think it does not fall in 0-31

Answer (score -4):

you can use

```
0 0 */45 * * php path/to/your/php/script
```

This will run the task at 00:00 (midnight) every 45 days.
source:
[Cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronjob#Format)

Comment: The divisible number 45 is not in the range 1-31 for days.

Comment: The 3rd place of the cron expression represents the day of the month (range from 1 to 31), not a straight-up day number.